# Why does the book The Martian mention the cubs, the beatles, and Three's Company?

Tags: books, the-martian

In the story the author asks how the Cubs are doing, has Mark watch Three's Company, and forces the Beatles upon him.  **Why is that?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The author explained in an [interview](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/writing-tips-and-advice-from-andy-weir-author-of-the-martian) that some of these items are things that he *personally* enjoys.

> **Q)** *In THE MARTIAN, Watney has access to his crewmates digital entertainment on Mars, including TV episodes of Three’s Company, a
> variety of Beatles songs, and digital books including The Mysterious
> Affair at Styles. Any reason you chose to work those specific examples
> into the novel?*
>
> **A)** *It’s a selection of things I loved when I was growing up.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Writing Tips and Advice From Andy Weir, author of THE MARTIAN](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/writing-tips-and-advice-from-andy-weir-author-of-the-martian)</sup></sub>

And that his love of the Cubs was an in-joke. How do you make a bad situation worse? By supporting the Cubs, that's how.

> *"I just thought that would be just the thing to make Mark's pathetic
> situation more pathetic."*